# python web scraping: how to pass bot protection detector?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

i am trying to scrape this website https://www.thefork.co.uk/search?coordinates=51.31475930000001%2C-0.5599501.

For some reason it knows I am scraping because I am getting this page

[image]

Here is my code. is there anything i can do to prevent the pop up?

I have already added time.sleep and also using undetected_chromedriver

Do i need to add more deplay using the time method?

```
import time
import requests
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_links():
    driver = uc.Chrome()
    driver.get(
        'https://www.thefork.co.uk/search?coordinates=51.31475930000001%2C-0.5599501')
    time.sleep(30)
    content = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    body = soup.body
    url = body.find_all('a', {'class': 'css-11jucl6 ei5oc307'})
    LINKS = []
    while True:
        urls = body.find_all('a', {'class': 'css-11jucl6 ei5oc307'})
        for url in urls:
            try:
                print("url", url)
                print("'https://www.thefork.co.uk'+url.get('href')",
                      'https://www.thefork.co.uk'+url.get('href'))
                LINKS.append('https://www.thefork.co.uk'+url.get('href'))
                df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'LINKS': LINKS
                })
                df.to_csv('Links.csv', index=False)
            except:
                pass
        next_page_button = body.find_all(
            'button', {'data-testid': 'pagination-next-button'})
        print("next_page_button", next_page_button)
        if next_page_button:
            button = body.find_all('a', {'class': 'css-1n6bxlv e1kntgv41'})
            next_page = button[0].get('href')
            next_page_full = 'https://www.thefork.co.uk'+next_page
            driver.get(next_page_full)
            time.sleep(5)
            content = driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
            body = soup.body
        else:
            break


def get_data():
    ADDRESS = []
    NAME = []
    TOTAL_REVIEWS = []
    REVIEW_RATING = []
    driver = uc.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    df = pd.read_csv('./Links.csv')
    R_LINKS = df['LINKS'].to_list()
    # print("R_LINKS",R_LINKS)
    for i in range(len(R_LINKS)):
        # print("i", i)
        driver.get(R_LINKS[i])
        time.sleep(10)
        content = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
        body = soup.body

        review = body.find_all(
            'span', {'class': 'css-1p78gjh e7dhrrp0'})
        print("review", review)
        if len(review) > 0:
            rating = review[0].getText()
            REVIEW_RATING.append(rating)
        else:
            REVIEW_RATING.append(0)

        total_reviews = body.find_all(
            'span', {'class': 'css-1a6cx75 eulusyj0'})

        if len(total_reviews) > 0:
            total_rating = total_reviews[0].getText()
            TOTAL_REVIEWS.append(total_rating)
        else:
            TOTAL_REVIEWS.append(0)

        name = body.find_all(
            'h1', {'class': 'css-md0073 e7dhrrp0'})[0].getText()
        NAME.append(name)
        print("name", name)
        address = body.find_all(
            'span', {'class': 'css-1lnlsqc eulusyj0'})[0].getText()
        ADDRESS.append(address)
        print("address", address)

    new_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'NAME': NAME,
        'ADDRESS': ADDRESS,
        'TOTAL REVIEWS': TOTAL_REVIEWS,
        'REVIEW RATINGS': REVIEW_RATING,
    })
    new_df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
    time.sleep(5)
    print(f'LINKS DONE..! {i+1}/{len(R_LINKS)}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # get_links()
    get_data()
```

Comment: `user-agent` and, less likely, `referer` headers

Answer (score 0):

Fooling the captcha is a difficult task, sorry to break it to you but it could be an almost impossible task. A few important things to try are using a headless browser, setting up proper request headers, using cookies you would have if you opened the site the "human" way, making a request to their API if you can.

Again this is almost impossible but there is a difference in this site when you start it from python and from the browser, if at some point you find the difference in state between both and simulate it you could skip the captcha and view the page directly. disclaimer: TONS OF WORK + when you factor in how many protections against crawling the site might have.

Hope this helps.